# Data of 1 folder gets added to another

Tags: python

I have a small script which checks if my object is present in image or not. If present then it writes the image to a folder.There are multiple sub-folders inside.On writing, the data for 1st folder works fine but when data is written to the 2nd sub-folder then the data of 1st folder is also appended along-with the data of 2nd folder

The code works perfectly fine except the problem that while writing the data to disk the data of 1st sub-folder is also appended to the data of 2nd sub-folder. Below is my code

```
def target_non_target(input_frames_folder,model_file,output):

    if not os.path.exists(output):
        os.makedirs(output,exist_ok=True)

    count=0
    folders = glob(input_frames_folder)

    img_list = []


    for folder in folders:
        folder_name=os.path.basename(folder)
        #print(folder_name)
        out_path = output +"\\" + folder_name
        print(out_path)
        os.makedirs(out_path,exist_ok=True)



        for f in glob(folder+"/*.jpg"):
            img_list.append(f)

        for i in range(len(img_list)):
            v1=os.path.basename(img_list[i])
            img_name = os.path.splitext(v1)[0]
            image = cv2.imread(img_list[i])
            orig = image.copy()

            image = cv2.resize(image, (28, 28))
            image = image.astype("float") / 255.0
            image = img_to_array(image)
            image = np.expand_dims(image, axis=0)


            print("[INFO] loading network...")
            model = load_model(model_file)


            (non_target, target) = model.predict(image)[0]

            if target > non_target:
                label = "Target"

            else:
                label = "Non Target"

            probab = target if target > non_target else non_target
            label = "{}: {:.2f}%".format(label, probab * 100)


            op = imutils.resize(orig, width=400)
            cv2.putText(op, label, (10, 25),  cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,0.7, (0, 255, 0), 2)

            if target > non_target:
                cv2.imwrite(out_path+"/"+"\\{}.jpg".format(img_name),orig)
            cv2.waitKey(0)

    #return target_op


frames_folder = ("C:\\Python36\\videos\\videos_new\\*")

model = ("C:\\Python35\\target_non_target\\target_non_target.model")

output_folder = ("C:\\Python35\\target_non_target\\Target_images_new\\")

target_check = target_non_target(frames_folder,model,output_folder)
```

Suppose there are 2 sub-folders A and B inside a main folder X.There will be many more sub-folders.While writing output to disk the data of A is written perfectly but while writing data for B the data of folder A and folder B both are getting appended into B folder. I want the data to be in their respective folders. Any idea what changes could be made in my script for getting the desired output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the `img_list = []` to initiate but you need to repeat this at the end of each folder loop to reset it back to empty.  Right now you are keeping all of your results and then when you move to the next folder you are keeping your previous results and adding on.

The very end of your `for folder in folders` loop needs to have `img_list = []`

**Updated full code:**

```
def target_non_target(input_frames_folder,model_file,output):

    if not os.path.exists(output):
        os.makedirs(output,exist_ok=True)

    count=0
    folders = glob(input_frames_folder)

    img_list = []

    for folder in folders:
        folder_name=os.path.basename(folder)
        #print(folder_name)
        out_path = output +"\\" + folder_name
        print(out_path)
        os.makedirs(out_path,exist_ok=True)

        for f in glob(folder+"/*.jpg"):
            img_list.append(f)

        for i in range(len(img_list)):
            v1=os.path.basename(img_list[i])
            img_name = os.path.splitext(v1)[0]
            image = cv2.imread(img_list[i])
            orig = image.copy()

            image = cv2.resize(image, (28, 28))
            image = image.astype("float") / 255.0
            image = img_to_array(image)
            image = np.expand_dims(image, axis=0)

            print("[INFO] loading network...")
            model = load_model(model_file)

            (non_target, target) = model.predict(image)[0]

            if target > non_target:
                label = "Target"
            else:
                label = "Non Target"

            probab = target if target > non_target else non_target
            label = "{}: {:.2f}%".format(label, probab * 100)

            op = imutils.resize(orig, width=400)
            cv2.putText(op, label, (10, 25),  cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,0.7, (0, 255, 0), 2)

            if target > non_target:
                cv2.imwrite(out_path+"/"+"\\{}.jpg".format(img_name),orig)
            cv2.waitKey(0)

        img_list = []   # this is the end of for folder in folders, reset list
    #return target_op


frames_folder = ("C:\\Python36\\videos\\videos_new\\*")
model = ("C:\\Python35\\target_non_target\\target_non_target.model")
output_folder = ("C:\\Python35\\target_non_target\\Target_images_new\\")
target_check = target_non_target(frames_folder,model,output_folder)
```

Comment: I am getting a lil bit of what u are trying to hint at. But i am quite new to python. Can you please help me out by making the suggested change at the desired position in the script please. I have a few more functions of similar fashion. If u can show me the change here i may be able to solve the issue in the other functions

Comment: Basically i am just confused whether to add img_list=[] after os.makedirs(out_path,exist_ok=True) or after this cv2.putText(op, label, (10, 25),  cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,0.7, (0, 255, 0), 2)

Comment: I added where it needs to be. Just pay attention to where each loop starts and stops based on indentation to figure out where the end of each loop is. `for folder in folders` is the base level indentation, so we need one indent in to be within that loop, and we need to update it at the end after the other internal loops to that one.

Comment: Thanks a lot brother This worked. I had also done the same after u suggested its just that my indentation was wrong. Corrected it seeing ur edited code and it worked. Thanks a lot once again :)

Comment: No problem Ankit :)

Comment: brother can u plz help me out in this one too.This is the second function in which i have the same problem as the previous. I tried img_list=[] also but the same issue still remains https://stackoverflow.com/q/55698757/11312863

Comment: Answered on there, indent your second img_list one more in.